Keycloak angular ssr login redirection not working
In my angular SSR app, i want login component redirect automaticaly to keycloak.
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private keycloakService: KeycloakService
  ) {
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("in my login component oninit");
    await this.keycloakService.login();
  }

}

Here the keycloak  login function :
  login() {
    console.log("redirecting vers keycloak")
    return this.keycloak?.login();
  }

I registered the keyclaok initialization as APP_INITIALIZER. Here its init method  :
async init(): Promise<void> {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const { default: Keycloak } = await import('keycloak-js');

      const config = { ... };
      this.keycloak = new Keycloak(config);

      const authenticated = await this.keycloak.init({
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/assets/keycloak/silent-check-sso.html",
      });

      console.log('Keycloak initialized successfully');

      if (authenticated) {
        let up = (await this.keycloak.loadUserProfile()) as UserProfile;
        up.token = this.keycloak.token || '';
        up.anonymous = false;
        this.setUserProfile(up);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to initialize Keycloak', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

When I change the onLoad: 'check-sso' parameter to onLoad: 'login-required', I m redirected to keycloak login page as expected.
Now I want to be redirected to only if the user navigate to  my app login page.
What am I missing?
